# How to target javascript element by it's onclick attribute via Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm working with a webpage that has a number of javascript buttons that are written like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addtocart('888%20B0007VBRUE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20',$(this),0)" class="btn btn-lblue pull-right">
```

Selenium can execute javascript, but I'm not quite sure how to format the javascript query to trigger the individual buy buttons.  I tried:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById("test").onclick = "addtocart('888%20B0007VBRUE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20',$(this),0)").click()
```

but this gives me the error `Message: document.getElementById(...) is null`.  How can I change what I've tried to get it to work?

Comment: I thought using fake links went out with browser sniffing. What is the point of `href="javascript:;"` when there are 3 classes already do to styling?

Comment: Didn't write the website in question, so I'm not really sure why they did it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have not added an id of `test` to your `<a>` tag. Also it is generally not advisable to lookup an element based on the value of its onclick handler.

Fixed code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="test" onclick="addtocart('888%20B0007VBRUE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20',$(this),0)" class="btn btn-lblue pull-right">
```

In addition, you need to switch one of your `"` for `'` in driver.execute script, because each `"` terminates the preceding string.

Example:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("test"),$(this),0)').click()
```